# При установке Ubuntu не работают клавиатура и мышь

Tags: ubuntu, hp

При установке Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) с USB-флешки(записывал Rufus'ом) перестает работать клавиатура и мышь. В первом окне выбора языка мышь работает ~2 сек. затем перестает, точнее не регистрируются нажатия, но курсор перемещать можно. Точно также при загрузке Ubuntu без установки, мышь работает нормально пару секунд, затем перестает реагировать на нажатия, но можно перемещать курсор. 
Компьютер:
Ноутбук HP 17 ab412ur, установленна Windows 10.
Пробовал подключить другую мышь, результат тотже.
Срочно нужно установить OS, что делать???
Спасибо.

Пробовал установить версию 16.04. Во время установки появляется надпись "Ubuntu", 5/5 точек загораются и ничего не происходит, просто экран "Ubuntu" и точки, при попытке загрузки OS с флешки тоже самое.

Comment: смените флэшку (я очень долго мучился оказалось что флэшка загнанная уже). и ставьте 16.04

Comment: Rufus'ом проверял флешку, вроде все ok, но при использовании в компьютере с виндой, винда ругаеся, и просит восстановить флешку, при этом, если согласится винда восстановить ее не может. При использовании на другом компьютере с Ubuntu, проблем нет. Возможно ,конечно, флешка уже "загнанная", так как в последнее время активно ее использовал.

Comment: у меня абсолютно непонятные ошибки были, сменил флэшку - и все сразу как по маслу пошло

Comment: Сменил флешку, установка 18 версии проходит нормально, но в конце при просьбе перезагрузиться, нажимаю Restart Now, компьютер зависает. Если принудительно перезагруизить нажатием кнопки питания, потом включить, система загрузится нормально, но после ввода пароля она зависает.

Comment: 16.04 попробуйте.

Comment: А ещё можно попробовать `netinstall` версию с псевдографическим интерфейсом.